# SEO in a backbone application so that google can index home, after phantomjs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo, phantomjs

I have Backbone website. I've used phantomjs so that search engines can look up though the js links (#!/something), following the _escaped_fragment_spec. I've checked using google webtools, to see how google will look my site, and mostly everything seems correct.

However, the main page (ex: www.example.com; the one with no #! in the link), google does not send the _escaped_fragment_spec, so the page is not sent to phantomjs, and js are not applied, therefore google is looking to a nearly empty page.

Does anyone knows how to indicate this, or solve the problem?

Thanks

Edit:
According to google (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)
You should add  to head, however I've added it, and webtools - see as google, does not seam to be procesing the main page as javascript. Any help? The site with problems is http://www.boletus-app.com/
Thanks

Comment: did you add in anything to your .htaccess to redirect to an 'seo server' or sub-domain, or did you handle in the escaped_fragment query parameter in the application itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question was to use the fragment meta tag

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

This will force all pages including the home page to be requested with escaped fragments

Answer (score 2):

The query parameter is named "_escaped_fragment", not "_escaped_fragment_spec".

Google will not execute the JavaScript in your client app. Google's AJAX application support is meant to support situations where AJAX/hashbang URLs from your site are linked to from other sites. For example, if someone links to `http://example.com/app#!my-route`, when Google's crawler encounters that link, it will translate it to `http://example.com/app?_escaped_fragment=my-route` before requesting it from your server. Your server code must handle this query parameter and generate the appropriate HTML to represent that URL for Google to index.